# visual studio 2017 apache cordova app wont debug on physical device?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, apache-cordova

[image]I can't Debug using a physical device in visual studio. It tells failure with an exception when I try to use my phone. my device debugging is enabled. When i build the in the browser simulator it works just fine.

Here is a pic of some of the error list errors.

Comment: Update your question with the exception you are getting.

Comment: it just shows up in the error list below there are like 36 errors, the first says "Failure:build failed with an exception. i dont know how to see what that exception is.